# React bootstrap form required validation not working

Tags: reactjs, validation, bootstrap-5

I am using this form for update details. So I am using required validation for avoid submit the null values. In here I remove before values and update with null values. It update with null values. Not show "Please fill out this field". This is my code.

```
  <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="formIssueName">
              <Form.Label>Issue Type</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                value={selectedIssue.name}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setSelectedIssue({
                    ...selectedIssue,
                    name: e.target.value,
                  })
                }
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
```

Help me to find the issue.